# Flume: Routing events to the proper topic partition with Kafka channel

Tags: apache-kafka, flume, flume-ng

In Flume, when using a Kafka channel, is there a way to influence what partition an event is sent to?

With Kafka **sink**, the `key` FlumeEvent header is apparently used to choose a partition but I could not find any documentation regarding partitions with the Kafka **channel**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kafka channel for Flume does not support mapping an Event header to a partition key out-of-the-box like KafkaSink does.

However, modifying it so that it does is not too complicated. As I am not sure I can share the code, I will just give directions:

1. add a configuration key for the name of the header which will be mapped to partition key
2. in inner class KafkaTransaction, replace `byte[]` in the type of member `serializedEvents` with something that can also hold a `String` key for each and every event (either an inner class, or even a Kafka `KeyedMessage<String, byte[]>`)
3. in method `KafkaTransaction.doPut(Event event)`, retrieve key from headers and store in `serializedEvents` together with serialized message
4. in method `KafkaTransaction.doCommit()`, use the key stored with serialized events instead of `batchUUID`.

**NOTE** that events in a transaction will no longer be guaranteed to be processed by a single KafkaChannel instance at the consumer end of the channel, so you'll have to check that it is compatible with your use case (regarding transaction size, etc).

Answer (score 1):

The channels do not have to worry about the partition. Because channels is the one writing it and channel is consuming messages, so no need to partition the messages. This is how the message is being created by flume-kafka-channel for writing.

```
new KeyedMessage<String, byte[]>(topic.get(), null,
              batchUUID, event)
```

But if your topic has more than one partition then lack of key would result in messages being sprayed into available partitions.

If you want more control on how the messages gets distributed in partition then you might want to look into Kafka's concept of Custom Partitioner, so you can create a class implementing `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Partitioner` interface, and set partitioner.class property with value equal to name of your class and make sure that your custom partitioner is available in your classpath. That way you can get control for every message before publishing and you can decide which partition the message should go to. You could set property `kafka.partitioner.class` in your flume channel configuration so that it gets picked up

Comment: Well, I **do** have other consumer groups, outside of Flume, for the topic in question so I care about the partition. What I hoped to do was map a header (origin host) to the key. My understanding of the code is that the `key` parameter of KeyedMessage<...> constructor is always null, so messages are always sprayed into available partitions. Is that right?

Comment: Yes thats right the messages are sprayed. One solution you might want to try is Kafka has concept of Custom Partitioner, so you can create a class implementing interface, and set partitioner.class property with value equal to name of your class and make sure that your custom partitioner is available in your classpath. That way you  can get control for every message before publishing and you can figure out which partition the message should go to. You could set property kafka.partitioner.class  in your flume channel configuration so that it gets picked up

Comment: Thanks, will look into your suggestion. You should edit your answer to include the `kafka.partitioner.class` trick as it is part of the solution.

Comment: I guess the Interface that should be implemented rather is `kafka.producer.Partitioner`. This is unfortunate because method `public int partition(Object key, int a_numPartitions)` doesn't receive the message as a parameter, only the key. So I guess the only solution would be to modify the Kafka channel source to map the key FlumeEvent header to message key in Kafka, like it is done for the Kafka Sink.

Comment: I eventually forked flume's KafkaChannel to add support for mapping an Event header to partition key in Kafka. I'm not sure I can share the code but my modifications were trivial. However, the original code mapped an internal transaction UID to partition key so that all events in a transaction are consumed by the other end of a single KafkaChannel instance. I was not interested in this feature (there's no sink at the other end of the channel in my case, I'm just using  KafkaChannel as a shortcut for Source->Channel->Kafka Sink) but I'm not sure what impact it might have in the general case.